# How can I use variable interpolation in HTML attributes (Knockout.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, template-engine

I'm using [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) as data binding framework, and have a [plugin](http://stevesanderson.github.io/statics/jsSnippets/StringInterpolatingBindingProvider.js) that allows {{expr}} syntax in my views. So far, so good. But I would also like to use this syntax in HTML attributes. Any ideas how I can manage that?

**Works**

```
<textarea>{{input}}</textarea>
<input type="text" data-bind="attr:{'value': input}" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: input" />
```

**Doesn't work**

```
<input type="text" value="{{input}}" />
```

I working demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/dC3Ge/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michael Best, the ko core committer, has a project Knockout.Punches meets exactly your requirement.

http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/

Comment: Perfect! This looks promising :)